# SOLVED Error 404.0 on IIS 10.0, but file exist in IIS directory

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, iis-10

I have installed IIS 10.0 on an Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. To use PHP-Files I have installed PHP over CGI and its works great. All php files working without an error. But when I go to ".../task/php/sql_task_success.php"

> Error 404.0 returns. MIME-TYPE from *.php is "application/octet-stream". The Error-Code from IIS is: 0x80070002 and the handler is: PHP.

I have tried to find a solution in this and other forums, but nothing works. I have checked the rights an IUSR has full access and the physical path exist and the file is in this directory the file.

Comment: We can't see your folder structure. Presumably that's not a correct relative path, but we can't really tell with the info provided.

Comment: The Path is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\dashboard\task\php\sql_task_success.php and the Url is: https://***:443/dashboard/task/php/sql_task_success.php?id=1

Comment: And what is the root folder of the specific website you've configured to serve this application within IIS?

Comment: This is the Root folder from this Website: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\

Comment: So you paste `https://***:443/dashboard/task/php/sql_task_success.php?id=1` into your browser window and get the 404? It doesn't reall make sense based on what you've said.  If you put a PHP file in the root folder and access it, does _that_ work?

Comment: Yes i become 404 by paste this in my browser. In the Root Folder the script working!

Comment: Maybe try it in each subfolder in turn until you start to have a problem? At the moment it doesn't make much sense and we can't see your server obviously so it's hard to diagnose anything specific.

Comment: The error is that the folder name "php". Idk why but now is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was the folder named "php" in the physical path . Thank you for this tip @ADyson :)